# Android Application Indexing in Google Search

Tags: android, indexing, google-play-services, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

how to get our android app to be found in Google Search Using App Indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately for you there's [Firebase App Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/):

> Firebase App Indexing gets your app into Google Search. If users have
>   your app installed, they can launch your app and go directly to the
>   content they're searching for. App Indexing reengages your app users
>   by helping them find both public and personal content right on their
>   device, even offering query autocompletions to help them more quickly
>   find what they need. If users don’t yet have your app, relevant
>   queries trigger an install card for your app in Search results.

Check the [Android Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app) to get started right away.